# Using Map.update in OCaml

Tags: dictionary, ocaml

I am attempting to change the value of a key in a map I made in OCaml:

```
module TestMap = Map.Make(String);;
let m = TestMap.empty;;
let m = TestMap.add "Chris" 1 m ;;
let m = TestMap.add "Julie" 4 m;;
```

This compiles file, but when I try to update the value at key `Julie` with:

```
let m = TestMap.update "Julie" 10 m;;
```

I get an error from the compiler:

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         'a option -> 'a option
```

I'm guessing that I'm maybe using the function incorrectly. I'm finding the documentation for Map.update pretty hard to understand:

```
val update : key -> ('a option -> 'a option) -> 'a t -> 'a t
```

Is my syntax or are my arguments incorrect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The update function works in a way different from what you think

```
key -> ('a option -> 'a option) -> 'a t -> 'a t
```

You see that second argument is a function which takes an `'a option` and returns an `'a option` so you don't directly update with a new value but rather pass a function which returns the new value, according to the previous one, eg:

```
let m = TestMap.update "Julie" (fun _ -> Some 10) m;;
```

This because, as documentation states, the passed `'a option` tells you if there was a mapping for the key and the returned `'a option` allows you to change it or even remove it (through `None`).

If you need just to update a mapping you can use `Map.add` again, there's no need to use more advanced `Map.update`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that ```Map.add``` updated existing Map entries!

Comment: Clarification: `add` does not update a map binding, but rather replaces it.